# Совмещение дерева и таблицы

Tags: c#

Есть дерево TreeView. Можно ли к нему добавить таблицу из 1-го столбика? Должно выглядеть примерно как редактирование свойств элемента.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть тебе лучше взять PropertyGrid? Этим элементом как раз и рисуется то, что ты показал на скриншоте. А так Windows Forms скуден на кастомизацию => тебе нужно пилить свой контрол.

Comment: В нём можно отобразить дерево также как в TreeView?

Comment: Типа того https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml

Comment: Ну эта хрень больше для всяких конфигураций=> если нужно просто отобразить данные, то это похоже на из пушки по воробьям.